# How to push an image id to docker repo

Tags: docker

When I run the command `docker ps` I get a list of containers like this:

```
6f8d5585918f        56058f3d1997    "test"              23 hours ago        Up 23 hours                         test1
18edba56bfeb        2482781314c7    "java -jar test2"   2 days ago          Up 2 days   0.0.0.0:8206->8484/tcp  test2
```

The second column is the image. I want to push the second image as test11 to our private repo. I don't have the files to build the image. How would I do this?

Comment: Do you want to push the current container state? Or just its base image?

Comment: I just need the base image pushed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you must tag the image ID.  The you must login to your private Docker registry.  (The correct name is *registry* and not *repository*.  A Docker registry holds repositories).  Then you push the image.

Substitute ***privateregistry*** with the hostname of the Registry.

```
docker tag 2482781314c7 privateregistry/test11
docker login privateregistry
docker push privateregistry/test11
```